# Undefined method 'to_key' for > Client::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy during edit only

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails application with the following code:
I have a ClientsController with

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    #GET to /users/:user_id/client/new(.:format)
    @client = Client.new
    @client2 = Client.new
  end

  def index
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @client = @user.clients
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    #create client linked to this user
    @client = @user.clients.build( client_params )
    if @client.save
      flash[:success] = "Client Updated"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render action::new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @client = @user.clients
  end

  private 

  def client_params
    params.require(:client).permit(:clientName, :clientEmail)
  end
end
```

I have my routes file like:

```
resources :users do
  resource :profile
  resources :clients
end
```

I have a user has_one association with profile and a has_many association with clients.

I am using Devise for authentication. I don't have a separate UsersController.

The code in ClientsController works fine for adding, editing and updating profile if I replace @client with @profile. But the code gives error when doing the same thing with Clients.

My edit.html.erb for Clients

```
<%= form_for @client, url: user_client_path do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <h5>Client's Name</h5>
    <%= f.text_field :clientName, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <h5>Client Email</h5>
    <%= f.text_field :clientEmail, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit "Save Profile", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I get an error that says

> undefined method `to_key' for 
>   Client::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy

I am doing this in dashboard/index.html.erb

```
<% @clients.each do |c| %>
  <%= link_to "Edit Clients", edit_user_client_path(id: c.id,user_id: current_user.id) %> 
  <br>
<% end %>
```

When clicking the link I get http://localhost:3000/users/26/clients/4/edit but then I get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find a one client in controller action, not an association. It should be

```
def edit
  @user=User.find(params[:user_id]) 
  @client = @user.clients.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: Where should this go?

Comment: @bigyan1einstein, I update the answer, it is edit action in ClientsController

Comment: Hey, thanks but I get a new error now that says "Couldn't find Client without an ID". How should I proceed?

Comment: @bigyan1einstein, please, add params of edit action from server logs

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. I get this from the console "ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `client_user_path' for #<#<Class:0x000000000d830290>:0x000000000eef5598>"

Comment: @bigyan1einstein Where do you run `rails server`? Look there, you can see server logs, there are many interesting things. And there do you have `client_user_path`? I can't see it in the question